# How to upload the image or photo in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am working on wso2 esb 4.7.0 ,

How can we  upload the image or photo in wso2 ESB throw Proxy service.

Can you give any simple example for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can send your Image as SWA or MTOM.  Here is a [sample](http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838822)